# How to populate a column in one dataframe by comparing it to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, pandas-groupby

I have a `dataframe` called `res_df`:

```
In [54]: res_df.head()
Out[54]:       
       Bldg_Sq_Ft        GEOID       CensusPop  HU_Pop  Pop_By_Area
0     753.026123  240010013002022       11.0     7.0          NaN
7      95.890495  240430003022003       17.0     8.0          NaN
8    1940.862793  240430003022021       86.0    33.0          NaN
24   2254.519775  245102801012021       27.0    13.0          NaN
25  11685.613281  245101503002000      152.0    74.0          NaN
```

I have a second dataframe made from the summarized information in `res_df`. It's grouped by the `GEOID` column and then summarized using aggregations to get the `sum` of the `Bldg_Sq_Ft` and the `mean` of the `CensusPop` columns for each unique `GEOID`. Let's call it `geoid_sum`:

```
In [55]:geoid_sum = geoid_sum.groupby('GEOID').agg({'GEOID': 'count', 'Bldg_Sq_Ft': 'sum', 'CensusPop': 'mean'})
In [56]: geoid_sum.head()
Out[56]: 
                      GEOID    Bldg_Sq_Ft  CensusPop
    GEOID                                          
    100010431001011      1   1154.915527        0.0
    100030144041044      1   5443.207520       26.0
    100050519001066      1   1164.390503        4.0
    240010001001001     15  30923.517090       41.0
    240010001001007      3   6651.656677        0.0
```

My goal is to find the `GEOID`s in `res_df` that match the `GEOID`'s in `geoid_sum`. I want to populate the value in `Pop_By_Area` for that row using an equation:

`Pop_By_Area = (geoid_sum['CensusPop'] * ref_df['Bldg_Sq_Ft'])/geoid_sum['Bldg_Sq_Ft']`

I've created a simple function that takes those parameters, but I am unsure how to iterate through the dataframes and apply the function.

```
def popByArea(census_pop_mean, bldg_sqft, bldg_sqft_sum):
    x = float()
    x = (census_pop_mean * bldg_sqft)/bldg_sqft_sum
    return x
```

I've tried creating a series based on the `GEOID` matches: `s = res_df.GEOID.isin(geoid_sum.GEOID.values)` but that didn't seem to work (produced all false boolean values). How can I find the matches and apply my function to populate the `Pop_By_Area` column?

Comment: you need `merge` dataframe `res_df` and `geoid_sum` on `GEOID` and do the calculation on the merged `df`. Docs of `merge`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `reindex`

```
geoid_sum = geoid_sum.groupby('GEOID').\
              agg({'GEOID': 'count', 'Bldg_Sq_Ft': 'sum', 'CensusPop': 'mean'}).\
               reindex(res_df['GEOID'])


res_df['Pop_By_Area'] = (geoid_sum['CensusPop'].values * ref_df['Bldg_Sq_Ft'])/geoid_sum['Bldg_Sq_Ft'].values
```

Comment: I think this almost works, but I'm getting an error: `ValueError: 'GEOID' is both an index level and a column label, which is ambiguous.`. Also, I assume I don't need those '\'s in the `geoid_sum`

Comment: I just changed it to `res_df['Pop_By_Area'] = (geoid_sum['CensusPop'].values * ref_df['Bldg_Sq_Ft'])/geoid_sum['Bldg_Sq_Ft'].values` and it worked. Thanks!